# How to target an element but not its nested element?

Tags: jquery, text, parent-child

How can I target an element but not its nested element?

For instance, I don't want to change the text in the `<span>` that is nested inside `<h1>`

HTML:

```
<h1>Change me <span> Don't change me</span></h1>
<h1>Change me <span> Don't change me</span></h1>
```

jQuery:

```
$("h1:first").text('Changed');
```

So the result should be:

```
<h1>Changed <span> Don't change me</span></h1>
<h1>Change me <span> Don't change me</span></h1>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go:

```
$( 'h1' )[0].firstChild.nodeValue = 'Changed ';
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/TqxrT/1/

Comment: I think this is one of those examples which proves that sometimes JavaScript is more concise than jQuery. :). +1

Comment: @Saeed jQuery's version is pretty short too: `$( 'h1' ).first().contents().first().replaceWith( 'Changed ' );`. Arnaud's solution is a bit longer because it explicitly searches for text nodes. In contrast, I just select the first child...

Answer (score 1):

```
$("h1:first").contents().filter(function() {
    return this.nodeType == 3;
}).replaceWith('foo');

alert($("h1:first").html());
```

What it does:

- [`.contents()`](http://api.jquery.com/contents/) returns all children of the element
- [`.filter(...)`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) keeps only the text nodes
- [`.replacewith()`](http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/) replaces the text nodes by some text

Try it here: http://jsfiddle.net/CZLuN/

Comment: Was just going to post the same, guess you were faster.

Comment: @arnaud, great solution. I didn't know about `nodeType` property of DOM elements.

Comment: nodeType is the type of the node (it can be an element, a document, a text node, etc). `3` is for text node. Not all browsers have constants of these, thus using the number directly. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/nodeType